# chai-as-promised rejection doesn't fail test but only print warning instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, chai

I'm using `chai-as-promised` to test my `readIndex(path): string` function.

**readIndex**() returns a promise which in turn try to open and parse to JSON a file named `index.json` in target folder.

See the following extract :

```
// readIndex.js
module.exports = path =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const buffer = fs.readFileSync(path + '/index.json')
      const data = JSON.parse(buffer.toString())
      resolve(data)
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
        reject(Error('file not found'))
      } else if (err instanceof SyntaxError) {
        reject(Error('format not json'))
      } else {
        reject(err)
      }
    }
  })
```

With my case test's mock, **the returned promise reject with the error** "*file not found*".

But actually I'm testing with a (supposed to be) valid case, that **should pass only if the promise resolved succesfully** ...

At least this is what I understood of the `promise.should.be.fulfilled` usage.

See the test in question :

```
// readIndex.test.js
chai.use(chaiAsPromised)
chai.should()

describe('SUCCESS :', () => 
  it('should resolve with a (markdown) string extrapoled from target folder index file', done => {
    const key = 'content success'
    mock(_mocks[key])
    const promise = readIndex('test')
    promise.should.be.fulfilled
    mock.restore()
    done()
  }))
```

With such a setup, **running the test does not make it fail**; it prints this message instead :

```sh
    SUCCESS :
          √ should resolve with a (markdown) string extrapoled from target folder index file
    (node:183516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError: expected promise to be fulfilled but it was rejected with 'Error: file not found'
    (node:183516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 10)
    (node:183516) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Of course, expected outcome should be a failed test run, and something like this in the console :

```sh
SUCCESS :
         1) should resolve with a (markdown) string extrapoled from target folder index file:

      AssertionError: expected '1' to equal '2'
```

This strange behaviour even lead to (funny and) incoherent warnings.

Using `promise.should.not.be.rejected`, I got "*expected promise not to be rejected but it was rejected*" but test still passed :

```sh
SUCCESS :
      √ should resolve with a (markdown) string extrapoled from target folder index file
(node:225676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError: expected promise not to be rejected but it was rejected with 'Error: file not found'
```

Actually my thoughts are that :

- A solution would to increase the level of test fail to **warnings**, but I didn't found it in the `chai-as-promised` documentation.
- Another solution would be to understand what layer is catching the Error/rejection, and is lowering it to a warning. Maybe a `chai-as-promised` default parameter ?

Comment: Assuming you need a Promise at all, there are cases where your promise will neither resolve nor reject. `if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {...}` needs `else {reject(err)}`.

Comment: yeah, you're right. It's in my code but I just shorten my code to post, sorry

Comment: you'll notice that I'm still entering this `if (err.code === 'ENOENT')`, as the warning first line attests it

Comment: Just thought I'd mention it, in case non-settlement of the promise might be a contributory factor.

Answer (score 5):

I just came across this little fact in the [`chai-as-promised` documentation](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) :

**The test "line"** (I don't have better word) **must be preceeded by a** `return` **statement**.

Let's take a look at their **first** example :

```
return doSomethingAsync().should.eventually.equal("foo")
```

The following is also very interesting :

> or if you have a case where return is not preferable (e.g. style
>   considerations) or not possible (e.g. the testing framework doesn’t
>   allow returning promises to signal asynchronous test completion), then
>   you can use the following workaround (where done() is supplied by the
>   test framework):

```
doSomethingAsync().should.eventually.equal("foo").notify(done);
```

It did the trick for me.

I hope it'll help people.

Comment: how did you fit in the `mock.restore()` statement?

Comment: I'm not really at ease with this subject, but I think that the promise kind of open a parallel thread, which doesn't interrupt the main one. Promise is instanciated, and test instrctions keep being executed.
I guess a better option would be to execute `mock.restore()` at the end of the `mock()`-consuming tests. 
What do you think ?

Comment: The fact is that, the mock is correctly read by the test (output is as exepected, and I white-boxed it to check `fs.readdir()` result) AND I don't check correct restore value before executing another test

Comment: `await` instead of  `return` should also do the trick (or probably, work much better even)

Answer (score 0):

I initially was using `chai-as-promised` there was some issue with promises not being correctly awaited that lead to hours of debugging my tests.

In the end I rolled my own solution.

### EDIT v2 - more concise

```
// test-utils.ts

import { expect } from "chai";

export const expectRejection = async (
  promise: Promise<any>,
  errMsg: string
): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    await promise;
  } catch (err) {
    expect(err.message).eq(errMsg);
    return;
  }
  throw Error('Promise was not rejected');
};
```

You can use the function like this in your tests

```
it('Function that fails', async () => {
  const errMsg = 'My example';
  const functionThatRejects = async () => {
    throw Error(errMsg);
  };
  await expectRejection(functionThatRejects(), errMsg);
});
```

And for completeness here is a unit test for the function.

```
import { expectRejection } from './test-utils';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('test-utils.ts', () => {
  describe('expectRejection(..)', () => {
    it('Function that fails', async () => {
      const errMsg = 'My example';
      const functionThatRejects = async () => {
        throw Error(errMsg);
      };
      await expectRejection(functionThatRejects(), errMsg);
    });

    it("Function that doesn't fail", async () => {
      const functionThatResolves = async () => null;
      try {
        await expectRejection(functionThatResolves(), "Random error message");
      } catch (err) {
        expect(err).match(/Promise was not rejected/);
        return;
      }
      throw Error('Should have already returned');
    });
  });
});
```

### v1 - more flexable

```
// test-utils.ts

import { expect } from "chai";

export const expectRejection = async (promise: Promise<any>) => {
  try {
    await promise;
  } catch (err) {
    return expect(err);
  }
  throw Error('Promise was not rejected');
};
```

You can use the function like this in your tests

```
it('Function that fails', async () => {
  const functionThatRejects = async () => {
    throw Error('My example');
  };
  const rejection = await expectRejection(functionThatRejects());
  rejection.match(/My example/);
});
```

And for completeness here is a unit test for the function.

```
// test-utils.spec.ts

import { expectRejection } from './test-utils';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('expectRejection(..)', () => {
  it('Function that fails', async () => {
    const functionThatRejects = async () => {
      throw Error('My example');
    };
    const rejection = await expectRejection(functionThatRejects());
    rejection.match(/My example/);
  });

  it("Function that doesn't fail", async () => {
    const functionThatResolves = async () => null;
    try {
      await expectRejection(functionThatResolves());
    } catch (err) {
      expect(err).match(/Promise was not rejected/);
      return;
    }
    throw Error('Should have already returned');
  });
});
```